# Render partial with refreshed data via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am pretty new to JS, but I hope I am missing something simple. I am trying to reload a partial that displays an image asynchronously. When a user clicks on the link below, it registers their vote, then (it should) render the pins partial with a new image from the database.

**index.html.erb (The link)**

```
<%= link_to 'Less', {:controller => "pins", 
                     :action => "create_view", 
                     :rank => 0,
                     :user_id => current_user.id, 
                     :pin_id => @pins.id
                     },
                     :method => "post", :remote => true %>
```

**pins_controller.rb (Method called by link)**

```
def create_view
  @view = View.new
  @view.user_id = params[:user_id]
  @view.pin_id = params[:pin_id]
  @view.rank = params[:rank]

  if @view.save
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
   end
  else
   render action: "new"
  end
end
```

**pins_controller.rb (Method that generates @pins)**

```
def index
  seen = Array.new
  max_pins = 20
  sex = current_user.sex
  views = View.user_views(current_user)
  seen = views.map(&:pin_id)
  @pins = Pin.new_pin(seen, sex)
```

**models/pins.rb**

```
def self.new_pin(pin_ids, sex)
  b = TRUE
  self.find(:first, :conditions => ["sex = ? AND active = ? AND id not in (?)", sex, b,    pin_ids], :order => "created_at desc" )
end
```

**index.html.erb (The DIV and partial)**

```
<div id="main_well">
     <%= render @pins %>
</div>
```

**create_views.js.erb (The javascript triggered on click)**

```
$('#main_well').html("<%= escape_javascript(render (partial: "pin", :locals => { pin: @pins})) %>");
```

**_pin.html.erb (The partial to be reloaded by JS)**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="center_well">
   <div class="well" style="background-image: url('<%= pin.image %>')" onclick="window.open('<%= pin.product_url %>','mywindow');"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have been at this for a while. Here's what I know. Clicking the link does remotely update the database. And if I change the JS to $('#main_well').remove(), clicking the link does remove the image asynchronously. However, I cannot for the life of my get the image to update onclick without refreshing the page. Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

As in the answer below, the instance variable @pins was not leading in the create_views method. Thus, regenerating the instance variable link this seemed to solve the problem.

**pins_controller.rb**

```
def create
 seen = Array.new
 max_pins = 20
 sex = current_user.sex
 views = View.user_views(current_user)
 seen = views.map(&:pin_id)
 @pins = Pin.new_pin(seen, sex)

 @view = View.new
 @view.user_id = params[:user_id]
 @view.pin_id = params[:pin_id]
 @view.rank = params[:rank]

 if @view.save
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to root_path }
     format.js
  end
 else
  render action: "new"
 end
end
```

However, this solution only serves to reload the partial successfully once. If I click the link, it reloads the image. However, if I click the link again, nothing happens. However, if I change the function like so it works perfectly:

**pins_controller.rb**

```
def create
 seen = Array.new
 max_pins = 20
 offset = rand(Pin.count)
 @pins = Pin.first(:offset => offset)

 @view = View.new
 @view.user_id = params[:user_id]
 @view.pin_id = params[:pin_id]
 @view.rank = params[:rank]

 if @view.save
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to root_path }
     format.js
  end
 else
  render action: "new"
 end
end
```

It seems that the local variable "view" is not being reloaded the second time I click the link. I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**views.rb**

```
def self.user_views(user)
  self.find(:all, :conditions => ['user_id = ?', user])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

In reference to the comments, this worked:

```
def index
  seen = Array.new
  max_pins = 20
  sex = current_user.sex
  views = View.user_views(current_user)
  seen = views.map(&:pin_id)
  @pins = Pin.new_pin(seen, sex)
end

def create
  seen = Array.new
  max_pins = 20
  sex = current_user.sex
  views = View.user_views(current_user)
  seen = views.map(&:pin_id)
  @pins = Pin.new_pin(seen, sex)

  @view = View.new
  @view.user_id = params[:user_id]
  @view.pin_id = params[:pin_id]
  @view.rank = params[:rank]

  if @view.save
     respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to root_path }
         format.js
     end
  else
     render action: "new"
  end
end
```

---

**Original Answer**

From looking at your code, it seems it *should* work, but I imagine there are syntax problems preventing it from doing so

---

**@pins**

You're calling `@pins` in a completely new action

The problem is that your `ajax` request is a new request (your instance is concluded after the initial HTTP request ends). This means your `@pins` instance variable is not persisting through the ajax call, and is likely why your partial won't render correctly

Try:

```
#app/controllers/pins_controller.rb
def index
    @pins = Pin.new_pin(seen, sex)
end

def create
    @pins = Pin.find(params[:id])
end
```

---

**Partial**

When calling your partial, you can then try this:

```
$('#main_well').html("<%=j render partial: "pin", :locals => { pin: @pins} %>");
```

This should work if your `@pins` variable is called properly

---

**Update**

```
def self.user_views(user)
   where(user_id: user.id)
end
```

Comment: The code above still did not work. It did, however, lead me to the answer. The problem was, indeed, that the instance variable was not available to create. When I copied the relevant code from the Index method into create, it works like a charm. Thanks so much for your help! I have been working on this for days.

Comment: No problem! Mind giving me an upvote if it helped? I'll amend the answer if you want to accept it too

Comment: It definitely helped. If you amend the answer I will give you the check, then I should have enough reputation to give you an upvote, too.

Comment: Ugh, I have one more question. The asynchronous reload, only seems to work one time. I click the link, and it reloads the image. But if I click the link again, nothing happens. I traced it back to the fact that this: `views = View.user_views(current_user)` does not re-execute on the second click. If I just pull a random pin like this it works fine: `offset = rand(Pin.count) @pins = Pin.first(:offset => offset)`

Comment: What is the `user_views` method?

Comment: I added it to the question above.

Comment: Refactored your user_views code -- have you tried sending `View.user_views(current_user.id)` ?

Comment: Or calling `id` on the passed object?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still working the same way where it only updates once asynchronously. Those now my (your) re-factored code looks much prettier.

Comment: Hmmm. There's got to be a reason for this -- can you post any logs etc from the asynchronous request?

Comment: I opened the JS console in Chrome and it displays this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ImagesLoaded' pins.js?body=1:3
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: I am not sure if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hmmmmm it's okay - but the thing we really need to see is the "Network" tab of the development tools area -- if you click on the network tab & look at what the response is, we can see what could be causing the issue

Comment: Here is the screenshot. I clicked the link once and it issues a get request. But the second time, it does not issue the same request. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/33t0wq7soyvofo5/Screenshot%202014-02-28%2011.50.54.png)

Comment: If you click one of the latest requests (which seem to have been performed fine), what do you see?

Comment: When I click on any of the create_view? items both the "preview" and the "response" say the same thing for all of them. `$('#main_well').html("\n<div class=\"row\">\n  <div class=\"center_well\">\n    <div class=\"well\" style=\"background-image: url(\'/system/pins/images/000/000/284/original/FDL_Vector.png?1392925571\')\" onclick=\"window.open(\'http://www.google.com\',\'mywindow\');\">\n    <\/div>\n\n  <\/div>\n \n<\/div>\n ");`

Comment: That looks like it's bringing back data? It might be the way you're handling your javascript -- why don't you try putting an alert in your JS file to see if it loads?

Comment: The alert loads as expect every time I click the link. It's just the image that still doesn't refresh. (Thanks a ton for sticking with me through all this)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$('#main_well').html("<%= escape_javascript(render (partial: "pin", :locals => { pin: @pins})) %>");
```

to this (add html_safe to the end of the escape_javascript call):

```
$('#main_well').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'pin', :locals => { pin: @pins}).html_safe %>");
```

EDIT

The problem is probably related to how the partial is being rendered. Does this work?

```
$('#main_well').html("<%= escape_javascript("#{image_tag pin.image}").html_safe %>")
```

Comment: That did not do it. Same result. It updates the database, but does not render a new image in the view.

Comment: Did you inspect the HTML where you expect the change to occur to see if it's just the image that isn't loading or none of the HTML is loaded asynchronously?

Comment: None of the HTML seems to be loading asynchronously. It is exactly the same after clicking the link. I tried putting this '<div id="main_well"><%= [at]pins %><%= render [at]pins %></div>' and the object is not updating.